# PHPPowerPoint : set line height between lines

Tags: phppowerpoint

I am using phppowerpoint to generate ppt files. I want to change default line height between lines in PPT.

[image: ppt slide screen grab]

here is bit of code I am using to generate ppt.

```
$shape->createParagraph()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPPowerPoint_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT)->setVertical(PHPPowerPoint_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
$textRun = $shape->createTextRun($ppt_build[$i][$k]['text'][$j]['textrun']);
$textRun->getFont()->setBold($ppt_build[$i][$k]['text'][$j]['bold']);
$textRun->getFont()->setSize($ppt_build[$i][$k]['text'][$j]['size']); //setName
$textRun->getFont()->setName($ppt_build[$i][$k]['text'][$j]['name']); //setName
$textRun->getFont()->setColor(new PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color($ppt_build[$i][$k]['text'][$j]['color']));
```

then creating a line break

```
$shape->createBreak();
```

I tried using giving 2 line breaks but it is more than I need.

I also tried solution mentioned here

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/discussions/273396

But with that solution it adds space only before and after the paragraph.

**is there any cheat sheet or list that contains xml nodes/elements/names used in xml files generated for powerpoint**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow below steps to achieve this

Inside
/* /powerpoint/PHPPowerPoint/Shape/RichText/Paragraph.php  */

```
private $_spacing;
```

also

```
/**
 * Get spacing
 *
 * @return PHPPowerPoint_Style_Spacing
 */
public function getSpacing() {
    return $this->_spacing;
}

/**
 * Set spacing
 *
 * @param    PHPPowerPoint_Style_Spacing        $spacing
 * @throws     Exception
 * @return PHPPowerPoint_Shape_RichText_Paragraph
 */
public function setSpacing($spacing = '100000') {
    $this->_spacing = $spacing;
    return $this;
}
```

Then inside  /PHPPowerPoint/Writer/PowerPoint2007/Slide.php

```
private function _writeParagraphs(PHPPowerPoint_Shared_XMLWriter $objWriter, $paragraphs) {
```

after

```
$objWriter->writeAttribute('lvl', $paragraph->getAlignment()->getLevel());
```

add

```
        if ($paragraph->getSpacing()) {
            $objWriter->startElement('a:lnSpc');
            $objWriter->startElement('a:spcPct');
            $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', $paragraph->getSpacing());
            $objWriter->endElement();
            $objWriter->endElement();
        }
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is a comment that this implements the percentage method of line spacing. So the paragraph will be as a % of the largest point value in all its text runs. Further, the percentages are divided by 1000...so the default in the code snippet above of 100000 is actually 100%.